# Why isn't there any standard automation testing tools for game development?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, game-engine

There are plenty of testing tools for creating software, a couple come to mind such as Test Complete and Selenium. But I’ve never seen or heard of a automation testing tool designed for the gaming industry, apart from the ones that come equipped with game engines such as Unity and Unreal. But these tools have to be built on, to my understanding they give devs the required code and you build on it to suit your game.

From what I understand automation testing in game development isn't really common, but is still done by some companies, and they do it through different methods such as developing AI that can play the game at a faster rate then a normal player  thus discovering the flaws and glitches of the game faster.  https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21397/how-common-is-automated-testing-in-game-development

But what I don't understand is why doesn't such a system exist. I know that games are vastly different and creating one tool that suits all games may be difficult but certainly not impossible, there is a lot to gain from such a tool.

Is it technical limitations? Or am I simply overthinking it.

I also feel that I should add that I have never used an automation testing tools, neither the ones I mentioned in the very beginning or the ones that come equipped with game engines.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take a look at this conference from Unite Europe 2015 :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OYojVTaqxY

In short lines this guys talks about Unity testing in games and about the fact that is feasible to make such testing. Though is a bit difficult you can actually get good results over an extended period of time, like testing in any other software.

He also talks about the testing package for Unity which you can download here(though it got deprecated and it got replaced in Unity 5.6 with an integrated runner) :
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/13802

Using these tools will allow you to write unit tests which can then be scalable. But once with the integration tests the scalability lowers and that code gets harder to mantain.

I wouldn't see why as an indie developer or as a rookie in gaming development you would want to use automated testing in your game, unit tests being easier to write and maintain. But as i said above these are actually nice tools which can get you out of trouble in many cases and that is understandable, though the time and effort required for developing the testing side of project increase.

Testing games nowadays, especially the high tier AAA games cannot be tested so easily because of the game logic complexity and that's why most companies tend to use AI for that reason.

I hope I answered to some of your questions and please correct me if I'm wrong.